# How to Add a "Scrolling Effect" to PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress

**SITUATION:** I have a fully working PHP module the function of which is to filter product categories and show users only relevant results. For reference, the page has 50 categories, instead of scrolling down looking at each one of them, user can filter only selected one they want to view.

*This is a very good example of a site that offers such functionality:
https://saijogeorge.com/best-marketing-tools/
-as you can see there are many categories, but if one is clicked the category is not only filtered but also the page is automatically scrolled.*

**PROBLEM:** The problem with my module is that after clicking on relevant categories the module doesn't scroll to actual results, but rather it just shows them in the block right under the filter. However, I want to make sure that the actual browser page automatically scrolls to the selected category right after the user filters a category.

**Experts out there, could anyone review the attached PHP  code and see how can I implement the scrolling effect.**

Attaching code of my module:

```
                    <?php 
                    $item_count_disp_all = 0;
                    foreach ($listItems as $item){
                        if( $item_count == "on" ){
                            @$item_count_disp_all += count(get_post_meta( $item->ID, 'qcopd_list_item01' ));
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <a href="#" class="categoryfilter-btn categoryfilter-active" data-categoryfilter="all">
                    <?php 
                        if(testmodule_get_option('testmodule_lan_show_all')!=''){
                            echo esc_html(testmodule_get_option('testmodule_lan_show_all'));
                        }else{
                            _e('Show All', 'qc-opd'); 
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if($item_count == 'on' and $infinityscroll!=1){
                            echo '<span class="opd-item-count-fil">('.esc_html($item_count_disp_all).')</span>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </a>
```

Comment: That is most likely not implemented via PHP. Dare I guess javascript?

Comment: Yup, PHP is server-side stuff. OP needs to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: PHP is a server side language, impossible to do with UI

Comment: Any recommendation on how to embed  .JS to this code?

Answer (score 1):

I analysed the page you linked with Firefox Inspect Element, and immediately noticed that there is a jQuery event linked to the clicking of every div that represents a category.
Specifically, the event triggers the following event:

```
function() {
  $(".listsInfo").hide();
  $(".listWindow").hide();
  $(".listWindow#" + $(this).attr("value")).show();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".lists").offset().top
  }, '1000', 'swing');
  window.location.hash = "";
  listWindowCheckForPressed();
  $("#livesearch").val("");
  return false;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Any ideas recommendations on embedding a similar .js script into the php code above?